# What does mean by Multiple instance of microservice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

suppose, if we have one machine of 2gb RAM, and one microservice takes 500mb to run

and as i understood if one request takes 1mb then max 500 users can request at a time,

if it proceeds we need to run with another instance is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; you're referring to increasing the replica count of your microservice so that it can service more than 500 users without risking performance problems. In such a case, it would be a good idea to increase the number of microservices to more than one.  If another 500 users are making requests to that second microservice, then you would want to spin up a third microservice, etc.  Kubernetes does a good job at this automatically for you

Comment: can we give entire 2gb to first instance? so we don't need another instance

Comment: yes, but doing that is risky because if/when you use up all 2GB, your microservice will run out of memory and crash.  You should instead set up some way of making sure either: another instance of your microservice is created when you reach a certain memory limit (slightly less than 2GB so your first mS doesn't go down), or prevent your mS from using any additional memory after it reaches a certain memory threshold (this should also be slightly below 2GB)

Comment: Juarez can you please help mw with this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62863295/onetomany-with-query-dsl-and-dto-pattern-problem